# Checking and replacing a duplicate in a single for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

So I have set up my code to be this (note I have my user input for the array and display of the results in another function and a beginner)

```
int main( )
{
    using namespace std;

    int a[8];

    populateArray(a, 8);

    cout<<"The array is: ";
    displayArray(a, 8);
    cout<<"\nThis array becomes: "<<sameElement(a, 8);

int sameElement(int a[], int size)
{
    using namespace std;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i ++)
        {
            if( a[i] == a[i +1])
            {
                a[i + 1] = 0;
                return i;
            }
            else
                {
                    return a[i];
                }
        }

}
```

Been trying to see if a user puts a duplicate number(that works fine and great). That same array that the user input I want to replace that duplicate to a zero. Sadly I get either a single 0, 1, or 2 and it replaces the entire array. not sure how to return it back to my main as it also says that I have nothing returning from my function despite invoking it in my function and trying to find the right way to return my function. I have declared my function on top and they both match with the parameter as well. So still don't see why I keep getting an issue of returning my function to main?

Example:

The array: 1 2 2 3 4 5 5 7
Array becomes 1 0 0 3 4 0 0 7

Comment: Do you see were `sameElement` returns? It will _always_ return on the first iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to replace duplicate entries of an array in `sameElement` function. You're getting single integer because `sameElement` function returns single integer.

Instead of returning value in for loop, let the function run through. Also note that `a[i+1]` will go over limit of array `a`, so you have to change ending condition to `size - 1`.

```cpp
void sameElement(int a[], int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        if( a[i] == a[i +1])
        {
            a[i] = 0;
            if(i + 1 == size - 1)
            {
                a[i + 1] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because the function no longer returns value, you must display it on its own.

```cpp
cout << "\nThis array becomes: ";
sameElement(a, 8);
displayArray(a, 8);
```

Lastly, I don't know if this is intentional but `sameElement` function will only find duplicate entries if they are next to each other: it won't turn `1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2` to zeroes.